# playwright: how to modify the context without creating new page

Tags: javascript, playwright

playwright: I have already created a page with options as bellow, how to modify the context without creating new page

```
const browser = await browserContext.browser();
const context = await browser.newContext({
    userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/65.0.3325.109 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1',
    viewport: {
      width: 1920, // iPhone X width
      height: 1080,
    },
    isMobile: true,
    hasTouch: true
  })
  const new_page = await context.newPage();
await page.goto('http://google.com/‘);

// here I want to modify the existed page options, change isMobile=false
// how to modify without create a new context and new page 
// I tried to find some info in playwright API document, seems no way to update the existed page options
```

Comment: You don´t use ```playwright.config.ts```? By using that config you can set different environments and the only thing you have to do is to switch between them. Or do you want to switch between contexts in one test execution ? You can configure a global set up and if necessary you can override properties in ```spec.ts```s [test configuration](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration). You can access you context at every ```test('my_test', async ({page, context, browser ....}))``` test as well.